# How can I change the text in a WPF menu item from the .cs file?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm learning WPF (this is my second day), and I'm trying to make a play/pause toggle menu item.  The program starts paused, with the menu item reading "Start"; when I click "Start", I'd like the menu item to change to "Pause".

```
<MenuItem Header="_Server">
    <MenuItem Header="Start" Click="ToggleRunningStatus" Name="toggleRunningMenuItem" />
</MenuItem>
```

I was hoping it'd be as simple as `toggleRunningMenuItem.SetText("Pause");` but that doesn't seem to be the case.  Thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have the header in your XAML set to "Start".

You can access that same property from code-behind:

```
toggleRunningMenuItem.Header = "Pause";
```

You don't even need to set a name for the menu:

```
private void ToggleRunningStatus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var menuItem = (MenuItem)e.OriginalSource;
    menuItem.Header = "Pause";
}
```

Comment: Whelp, that's embarrassing.  I saw the Header had some strange (i.e. non-string) type and didn't give it a second glance.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the Name attribute to x:Name so:

```
<MenuItem Header="Start" Click="ToggleRunningStatus" x:Name="toggleRunningMenuItem" />
```